# What is difference between Combine and RxSwift?

Tags: rx-swift, combine

I wonder if there is an excellent document to show the difference between Combine and RxSwift?

It's good for me to quickly learn the `Combine` because I already had good knowledge about `RxSwift`

Comment: You can check this post https://quickbirdstudios.com/blog/rxswift-combine-transition-guide/#:~:text=RxSwift%20supports%20iOS%209%20and,and%20support%20for%20more%20platforms.

Comment: @ĐứcBùi Thank you, I will check your suggestion

Answer (score 16):

Đức Bùi posted a good article detailing the surface level differences. In this answer, I'll cover some other differences I've discovered...

A `Cancellable` and a `Disposable` are much more different than the article suggests. The former is required to *keep the subscription alive*, while the latter is only needed if you want to explicitly kill the subscription. So Disposables can be ignored, but Cancellables never can.

The `share(replay: x)` operator in Combine is equivalent to RxSwift's `.share(replay: x, scope: .forever)` and there is no notion of a share `.whileConnected`. This means that shared publishers can't be restarted like shared Observables can.

Other issues:

- The back-pressure handling in Combine is an extra complication that
  you will never need, but have to deal with anyway.
- Every operator in Combine returns a different type and most of them are
  wrappers around their source type, so they get extremely complex very
  fast. The `eraseToAnyPublisher()` operator provides some relief but
  having to constantly use it is its own torture.
- The lack of UIKit support is tough. It's better to go with SwiftUI. As
  such, it's not a simple translation from one API to the other, but a
  complete rewrite.
- You will quickly find yourself reaching for third-party libraries in
  order to fill in the holes that Combine left open. If you are switching
  to Combine in order to avoid third-party libraries, you've defeated the
  purpose.

As for benefits? I have only found one. Combine Subjects are thread safe whereas RxSwift Subjects are not. In RxSwift you rarely need Subjects anyway, in Combine you need them constantly.